# Compound Growth

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is along the same lines as the population growth problem but a little more involved. I'm really lost on how to go about it. The question is:

---

Suppose that each time a savings bank compounds the interest, you make an additional deposit $D(t)$. Show that 
$$N(t+\Delta t)=N(t)(1+\frac{I}{n})+D(t)$$

(if $D(t)$ is negative, this is a withdrawal). If an initial deposit is made and \$50 is withdrawn every month (with $I$ percent interest compounded every month), then how much money must be initially deposited such that the \$50 can be withdrawn every month FOREVER!

---

Most problems I can at least make an attempt and have an idea but I'm completely lost on where to begin for this. I understand what it's asking for but I just don't know how to get the answer.

Comment: What is $N(t)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that you need the interest in one month to be at least $\$50.$  Then you have a least as much after one month as you started with, so again will be even or ahead after month two...  How much do you need to deposit to yield $\$50$ per month?

Comment: Okay I see what you're getting at. But in this case what is the difference between $N(t)$ and $N(t+\Delta t)$?

Comment: One is the balance at time $t$ and the other the balance at time $t+\Delta t$.  It is true that in this calculation they are equal, but that is not given.  You might have a different $D(t)$, which would change $N(t)$  My point is that you should recognize $N(t)=N(t+\Delta t)$ and use that to determine $N(t)$, which is then $N(0)$